# xtable - background colour of added rows

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I'm trying to make a table with inserted summary rows using xtable and knitr. I'd like to have these inserted lines in a different colour. Using the add.to.row option, I've managed to either insert the lines *or* change the colour, but not both at the same time.

The reason I'm inserting the rows within xtable, rather than ahead of time, is that I want the "total" row to be spread over two columns due to its length in my original dataset. So the required solution would have both multicolumn cells in the summary row and a different-colour background.
I'm at the very beginning of my Latex learning curve, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example, including a fake dataset:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<try, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results = 'asis'>>=  
library(xtable)
dat <- data.frame(type = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), a = c(1:5, 1:5), b = 1:10, c = 21:30)
temp <- ddply(dat, .(type), summarize, SumB = sum(b))

rws <- which(dat$a == 5)
col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws)) ## colour definition prepared, but not used

#Making the command for inserting summary rows
temp$insert <- ""
for(i in 1:nrow(temp)){
    temp[i,]$insert <- sprintf("\\multicolumn{3}{l}{Total %s} &
        \\multicolumn{1}{c}{%d} \\\\ ", temp[i,]$type, temp[i,]$SumB)
            }

print(xtable(dat, align = "llccc"), 
    include.rownames=FALSE,
    booktabs = TRUE, 
    sanitize.text.function=function(x){x},
    add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws),
        command = paste(temp$insert, sep = ",")))

@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say `colortbl` is enough, no need for xcolor here. 
Try to add `rowcolor` to your command like this:

```
print(somextable,                  
              floating=FALSE, 
              hline.after=NULL,                  
              size="\\footnotesize",
              add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0,nrow(somextable),0,
                                       1,2,3,
                                       4,5,6,
                                       7,8,9,10,11
                                       ), 
              command=c('\\toprule ',
                        '\\midrule ',
                        '\\bottomrule',
                        '\\\\ \\rowcolor[gray]{.9}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\\\ \\rowcolor[gray]{.9}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\\\ \\rowcolor[gray]{.9}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}',
                        '\\rowcolor[gray]{.97}'
                        )
                              )
              )
```

should also work with generically created rows in add.to.row.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, because what I get from running it on my posted fake dataset is a pdf with a running line of all of the table's values: "type a b c 1 a 1 1 21 2 a 2 2 22 3 a 3 3 23 4 a 4 4 24 5 a 5 5 25 6 b 1 6 26 7 b 2 7 27 8 b 3 8 28 9 b 4 9
29 10 b 5 10 30"... Any hints?

Comment: In my example the `somextable`object is already of class `xtable`. That induces the `print.xtable` method. Sounds like you forgot xtable()?

Comment: Ah, yes. After correcting that glaring problem and fiddling around for a bit, it works. Thanks!